# Streaming Camera on .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, android, maui, rtsp

I'm trying to create an rtsp server to stream cell phone camera to .net MAUI and display on screen what I'm streaming.

I am using [Camera.MAUI](https://github.com/hjam40/Camera.MAUI) and specifically mediaRecorded then pass the file it is writing to as a stream to Libvlc, kind of like [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) does. I have done several trials without getting anything right it seems that libvlc can't recognize the incoming stream.

```
public async void StreamCameraAsync()
    {
        var RecordingFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.CacheDirectory, "Video1.mp4");

        cameraView.Camera = cameraView.Cameras.First();

        await cameraView.StartRecordingAsync(RecordingFile, new Size(1280, 720));

        var serverIp = "";
        var streamUrl = $"rtsp://{serverIp}:8090/stream";

        try
        {
            using (Stream fsSource = File.Open(RecordingFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                Core.Initialize();

                var libVlc = new LibVLC(enableDebugLogs: true);

                var streamMediaImput = new StreamMediaInput(fsSource);

                var media = new Media(libVlc, streamMediaImput);
                media.AddOption(":no-audio");
                media.AddOption($":sout=#transcode{{vcodec=h264,fps=25,acodec=none}}:rtp{{mux=ts,sdp={streamUrl}}}");
                media.AddOption(":sout-keep");

                var player = new MediaPlayer(media);

                player.Play();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

VLC Log:

```
[VLC] [b40000774af55740/0] libvlc libvlc: VLC media player - 3.0.18-rc2 Vetinari
[VLC] [b40000774af55740/0] libvlc libvlc: Copyright © 1996-2022 the VideoLAN team
[VLC] [b40000774af55740/0] libvlc libvlc: revision 3.0.18-rc2-28-g2d06859eb4
[VLC] [b40000774af55740/0] libvlc libvlc: configured with ../configure  '--host=aarch64-linux-android' '--build=x86_64-unknown-linux' '--with-contrib=/builds/videolan/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/aarch64-linux-android' '--prefix=/builds/videolan/vlc-android/vlc/build-android-aarch64-linux-android/install/' '--with-pic' '--disable-nls' '--enable-live555' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-avformat' '--enable-swscale' '--enable-avcodec' '--enable-opus' '--enable-opensles' '--enable-matroska' '--enable-taglib' '--enable-dvbpsi' '--disable-vlc' '--disable-shared' '--disable-update-check' '--disable-vlm' '--disable-dbus' '--enable-lua' '--disable-vcd' '--disable-v4l2' '--enable-dvdread' '--enable-dvdnav' '--enable-bluray' '--disable-linsys' '--disable-decklink' '--disable-libva' '--disable-dv1394' '--enable-mod' '--disable-sid' '--enable-gme' '--disable-tremor' '--disable-mad' '--enable-mpg123' '--disable-dca' '--disable-sdl-image' '--enable-zvbi' '--disable-fluidsynth' '--enable-fluidlite' '--disable-jack' '--disable-pulse' '--
[VLC] [b40000774af55740/b4000076fafeef70] libvlc libvlc: plug-ins loaded: 368 modules
[VLC] [b40000773af767a0/0] libvlc logger: looking for logger module matching "any": 4 candidates
[VLC] [b40000773af767a0/0] libvlc logger: using logger module "android_logger"
[VLC] [b40000774af55740/1799] libvlc libvlc: translation test: code is "C"
[VLC] [b40000773af771c0/1799] libvlc keystore: looking for keystore module matching "memory": 3 candidates
[VLC] [b40000773af771c0/1799] libvlc keystore: using keystore module "memory"
[VLC] [b40000774af55740/1799] libvlc libvlc: CPU has capabilities FPU 
[VLC] [b40000775af6f060/1799] libvlc generic: creating audio output
[VLC] [b40000777af8bbc0/1799] libvlc audio output: looking for audio output module matching "any": 4 candidates
[VLC] [b40000777af8bbc0/1799] libvlc audio output: using audio output module "android_audiotrack"
[VLC] [b40000775af6f060/1799] libvlc generic: keeping audio output
[VLC] [b4000077baf65200/1799] libvlc input: Creating an input for 'imem://'
[VLC] [b40000773af65ac0/1894] libvlc stream output: using sout chain=`transcode{vcodec=h264,fps=25,acodec=none}:rtp{mux=ts,sdp=rtsp://:8090/stream}'
[VLC] [b40000773af65ac0/1894] libvlc stream output: stream=`rtp'
[VLC] [b40000774af56ea0/1894] libvlc stream out: looking for sout stream module matching "rtp": 22 candidates
[VLC] [b40000774af56ea0/1894] libvlc stream out: set config option: sout-rtp-mux to ts
[VLC] [b40000774af56ea0/1894] libvlc stream out: set config option: sout-rtp-sdp to rtsp://:8090/stream
[VLC] [b40000774af57840/1894] libvlc mux: looking for sout mux module matching "ts": 11 candidates
[VLC] [b40000774af57840/1894] libvlc mux: shaping=200000 pcr=70000 dts_delay=400000
[VLC] [b40000774af57840/1894] libvlc mux: using sout mux module "mux_ts"
[VLC] [b40000773af65ac0/1894] libvlc stream output: muxer support adding stream at any time
[VLC] [b40000773af65ac0/1894] libvlc stream output: muxer prefers to wait for all ES before starting to mux
[VLC] [b40000774af56ea0/1894] libvlc stream out: RTSP stream at /stream
[VLC] [b40000774af56ea0/1894] libvlc stream out: net: listening to * port 8090
[VLC] [b40000774af56ea0/1894] libvlc stream out: maximum RTP packet size: 1400 bytes
[VLC] [b40000774af56ea0/1894] libvlc stream out: RTSP: adding /stream/trackID=0
[VLC] [b40000774af56ea0/1894] libvlc stream out: sdp=
[VLC] v=0
[VLC] o=- 16752055450727077990 16752055450727077990 IN IP4 localhost
[VLC] s=Unnamed
[VLC] i=N/A
[VLC] c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
[VLC] t=0 0
[VLC] a=tool:vlc 3.0.18-rc2
[VLC] a=recvonly
[VLC] a=type:broadcast
[VLC] a=charset:UTF-8
[VLC] m=video 0 RTP/AVP 33
[VLC] b=RR:0
[VLC] a=rtpmap:33 MP2T/90000
[VLC] [b40000774af56ea0/1894] libvlc stream out: using sout stream module "stream_out_rtp"
[VLC] [b40000773af65ac0/1894] libvlc stream output: stream=`transcode'
[VLC] [b40000774af56d40/1894] libvlc stream out: looking for sout stream module matching "transcode": 22 candidates
[VLC] [b40000774af56d40/1894] libvlc stream out: set config option: sout-transcode-vcodec to h264
[VLC] [b40000774af56d40/1894] libvlc stream out: set config option: sout-transcode-fps to 25
[VLC] [b40000774af56d40/1894] libvlc stream out: set config option: sout-transcode-acodec to none
[VLC] [b40000774af56d40/1894] libvlc stream out: Checking codec mapping for none got none 
[VLC] [b40000774af56d40/1894] libvlc stream out: codec audio=none 0Hz 0 channels 96Kb/s
[VLC] [b40000774af56d40/1894] libvlc stream out: Checking video codec mapping for h264 got h264 
[VLC] [b40000774af56d40/1894] libvlc stream out: codec video=h264 0x0 scaling: 0.000000 0kb/s
[VLC] [b40000774af56d40/1894] libvlc stream out: using sout stream module "stream_out_transcode"
[VLC] [b4000077baf65200/1894] libvlc input: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
[VLC] [b4000077baf65200/1894] libvlc input: using default timeshift path
[VLC] [b4000077baf65200/1894] libvlc input: `imem://' gives access `imem' demux `any' path `'
[VLC] [b40000773af74a60/1894] libvlc input source: creating demux: access='imem' demux='any' location='' file='(null)'
[VLC] [b40000774af55a00/1894] libvlc demux: looking for access_demux module matching "imem": 7 candidates
[VLC] [b40000774af55a00/1894] libvlc demux: no access_demux modules matched
[VLC] [b40000775af79160/1894] libvlc stream: creating access: imem://
[VLC] [b40000775af79160/1894] libvlc stream: looking for access module matching "imem": 25 candidates
[VLC] [b40000775af79160/1894] libvlc stream: using access module "imem_access"
[VLC] [b40000775af84920/1894] libvlc stream: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_read": 26 candidates
[VLC] [b40000775af84920/1894] libvlc stream: using 16777216 bytes buffer, 16777216 bytes read
[VLC] [b40000775af84920/1894] libvlc stream: using stream_filter module "prefetch"
[VLC] [b40000775af89b60/1894] libvlc stream: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 26 candidates
[VLC] [b40000775af89b60/1894] libvlc stream: Trying Lua scripts in /data/user/0/com.companyname.camera.maui.test/files/.share/lua/playlist
[VLC] [b40000775af89b60/1894] libvlc stream: Trying Lua scripts in /data/app/~~2SYo5E6tSlhHmG7v1mKD1A==/com.companyname.camera.maui.test-IMTvzTzmCQod-tTmef4mYQ==/lib/arm64/vlc/lua/playlist
[VLC] [b40000775af89b60/1894] libvlc stream: Trying Lua scripts in /data/app/~~2SYo5E6tSlhHmG7v1mKD1A==/com.companyname.camera.maui.test-IMTvzTzmCQod-tTmef4mYQ==/share/vlc/lua/playlist
[VLC] [b40000775af89b60/1894] libvlc stream: no stream_filter modules matched
[VLC] [b40000774af55b60/1894] libvlc stream_directory: looking for stream_directory module matching "any": 1 candidates
[VLC] [b40000774af55b60/1894] libvlc stream_directory: no stream_directory modules matched
[VLC] [b40000773af74a60/1894] libvlc input source: attachment of directory-extractor failed for imem://
[VLC] [b40000775af89b60/1894] libvlc stream: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 26 candidates
[VLC] [b40000775af89b60/1894] libvlc stream: using stream_filter module "record"
[VLC] [b40000773af74a60/1894] libvlc input source: creating demux: access='imem' demux='any' location='' file='(null)'
[VLC] [b40000774af55b60/1894] libvlc demux: looking for demux module matching "any": 50 candidates
[VLC] [b40000773af6a2c0/1894] libvlc xml reader: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
[VLC] [b40000773af6a2c0/1894] libvlc xml reader: using xml reader module "xml"
[VLC] [b40000774af55b60/1894] libvlc demux: subtitle demux discarded
[VLC] [b40000774af55b60/1894] libvlc demux: TS module discarded (lost sync)
[VLC] [b40000774af55b60/1894] libvlc demux: MOD validation failed (ext=)
[VLC] [b40000774af55b60/1894] libvlc demux: trying url: imem://
[VLC] [b40000774af55b60/1894] libvlc demux: CPU flags: 0x00000068
[VLC] [b40000774af55b60/1894] libvlc demux: couldn't guess format
[VLC] [b40000774af55b60/1894] libvlc demux: this does not look like an MPEG PS stream, continuing anyway
[VLC] [b40000774af55b60/1894] libvlc demux: using demux module "ps"
[VLC] [b4000077baf65200/1894] libvlc input: starting in async mode
[VLC] [b40000773af779a0/1894] libvlc demux meta: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
[VLC] [b40000773af779a0/1894] libvlc demux meta: Trying Lua scripts in /data/user/0/com.companyname.camera.maui.test/files/.share/lua/meta/reader
[VLC] [b40000773af779a0/1894] libvlc demux meta: Trying Lua scripts in /data/app/~~2SYo5E6tSlhHmG7v1mKD1A==/com.companyname.camera.maui.test-IMTvzTzmCQod-tTmef4mYQ==/lib/arm64/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[VLC] [b40000773af779a0/1894] libvlc demux meta: Trying Lua scripts in /data/app/~~2SYo5E6tSlhHmG7v1mKD1A==/com.companyname.camera.maui.test-IMTvzTzmCQod-tTmef4mYQ==/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[VLC] [b40000773af779a0/1894] libvlc demux meta: no meta reader modules matched
[VLC] [b4000077baf65200/1894] libvlc input: `imem://' successfully opened
[VLC] [b40000774af55b60/1894] libvlc demux: garbage at input from 509, trying to resync...
```

Do you happen to have any suggestions on how to approach the problem?

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out which part the snippet is. Is this supposed to _send_ to the server or _display_ a stream _from_ the server?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods The code is about starting camera recording and initializing libvlc to stream to RTSP

Comment: do you have any reason to think the data created by `CamaeraView` is a valid `rtsp` stream?  This seems like a huge assumption

Comment: _"this does not look like an MPEG PS stream, continuing anyway [...] **garbage at input from 509**, trying to resync... "_ ... I would really be surprised if going through the filesystem got you anywhere near streaming.